# Selecionar resultado, e mostrar apenas se todas forem equivalentes

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-select

Estou dando manutenção em um banco de dados, e estou com a situação seguinte; 
no banco eu tenho 5 colunas em uma tabela, são:

> ID(PK)|IDBilhete|Resultado|PrestadoConta|Data

Eu tenho que filtrar para o usuário ver, apenas as IDBilhete que esteja faltando resultado, ou que já tenha os resultados todos conferidos.

Usam normalmente `select * from bilhetes` pra retornar tudo, e vem algo similar a isso:

> 00|BFF554|0|0|21/12/2017
>
> 01|BFF554|1|0|21/12/2017
>
> 02|BFF554|2|0|21/12/2017
>
> 03|CCC154|1|0|22/12/2017
>
> 04|CCC154|3|0|22/12/2017
>
> 05|CCC154|1|0|22/12/2017

Então quero agrupar os IDBilhete repetidos apenas se todas as colunas 'resultado' dessa ID, forem igual a um valor específico.

Ex: Me retorne as IDBilhete apenas se todas as colunas 'resultado' for igual a 0!
Então se BFF554 tiver todas as 3 colunas resultado com o valor 0, a query me retorna essa ID, caso uma das colunas de resultado não seja o valor  0, essa ID não me interessa.

Comment: Oi , eu posso te ajudar só que sua pergunta está confusa, tem como explicar novamente

Comment: Você quer agrupar por idbilhete, mas no caso se tiver muitos valores acima de 0 , só aparecer uma vez?

Comment: Oi, é que no banco estou tendo que agrupar os resultados baseados em uma coluna que tem IDs repetidos, mas quero agrupar o resultado apenas se a outro coluna 'resultado' forem todas iguais a um condição específica.

Comment: Por acaso não era só agrupar por IDBilhete,Resultado e trazendo quantos cada um trouxe?

Comment: Você quis dizer, fazendo um `select count(resultado) from bilhetes where resultado = 0 group by IDBilhete` ? mas como eu filtraria pra me retornar apenas se todos os resultados forem igual a 0 por exemplo?

Comment: select count(resultado) from bilhetes group by IDBilhete, Resultado

Comment: Ae no caso se não quiser que apareça o zero, select count(resultado) from bilhetes Where Resultado > 0 group by IDBilhete, Resultado

Comment: é, mas o que quero é mostrar apenas se, naquela ID específica, todos os resultados sejam 0, se qualquer um dos resultados daquela determinada ID não for igual a 0 eu não quero ver aquela ID! acho que só fazendo um cursor né?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select bi.*
   from 
   bilhetes as bi  where 
      bi.IDBilhete not in (
                       select b.IDBilhete from bilhetes as b Where 
                       Resultado > 0 
                       )
 group by bi.IDBilhete

Tu tira primeiro os idbbilhetes que tem resultado maior que zero, e depois tu agrupa o resto.

Comment: Deu certo a resposta?

Comment: SIm, perfeito! obrigado